# Turn Node MCU into a PLC which is integrated Lora module for IoT application

Tags: plc, nodemcu, modbus, lora

I've built a PLC that supports Lorawan and Modbus protocol using Node MCU. I managed to make it possible with Modbus by using OpenPLC. Everything worked well apart from its limitation in the distance of data transmission or receipt. Thus, I thought of using the Lora module to overcome this weakness but still keep the Modbus function for some necessary cases. Some tough problems arise along with this idea were:

*1. How to link Lora end node with OpenPLC when they are far away?*

*2. If Lora gateway takes the role of the station to intake data so how are we able to take them for handling in OpenPLC Editor?*

I've been being stuck in both ways for days. How should I deal with this problem or are there anyway else for me to accomplish this? Someone who has experience with this could give me a suggestion?

Comment: Solve what problem?  You need to use the edit button to rewrite this so that it states a specific issue supported by full details.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I adjusted my post for more specifically. Hope you are clear about it.

Comment: This is still not a specific or answerable question.  You're basically asking someone to design your whole system, which is too broad to fit here, and worse, you're doing it without providing the constraints.  Probably you should start by doing some of your own research to see if the (unspecified) data you need to move is even really something for which LoRaWAN or any other LoRa scheme is suitable.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Foremost, I didn't intentionally require anyone to design my entire system even if you feel the post was (I'm not a native speaker so sometimes it can make you misunderstand). Just a suggestion or possible idea for connecting OpenPLC with sensor or actuator put at a long-distance via Lora technology would be very precious to me. And if it's still too wide for a post, I  think I can't separate it into smaller ones anymore. Secondly, I'm using a temperature sensor and another digital sensor to fetch respective data for monitoring and controlling HMI.

Comment: This site for *specific problems* only, not general hints or non-specific advice.   As in the previous comment, you should start by doing some self research on the possibilities of this technology to see if it is even applicable to your need.  Look at the sorts of things LoRa[WAN] is usually used for, in terms of message size, interval, and the general lack of reliability.  There is a lot of expertise here including on LoRaWAN, but SE sites are meant for what remains after doing basic research, they are not a substitute for doing your own research, nor a place to ask for examples.

Comment: I'll notice your advice next time. Perhaps, I should do my own research more deeply before questioning it. Thanks.